# How to load a minified concatinated js file with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gruntjs, requirejs

I'm new to grunt and file optimalisation. I have combined some JavaScript files (with grunt concat) into one file release.js and then minified it into release.min.js.

Now I am loading the combined files (they are jQuery ui widgets) with a requirejs script.

My question is, is this the right way to do this? Look's kinda strange to reference release.min.js four times. Is this causing requirejs to load the release.min.js four times? Or only once? It would be silly to load a big minified file a few times over.

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: '/site/scripts',
shim: {
    layout: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
    } ,
    serviceTraining:  {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
    },
    serviceMail:  {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
    },
    forms:  {
        deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui']
    }
},

paths: {       
    layout: 'custom/release/release.min',
    forms: 'custom/release/release.min',
    serviceTraining: 'custom/release/release.min',
    serviceMail: 'custom/release/release.min'
    }
});

require(['layout', 'serviceMail', 'serviceTraining', 'forms'], function() {

$(function() {

    // theme
    var layoutPlugin = $( "body" ).layout({ siteName: "Website name", domainName: "website.com" });
    layoutPlugin.layout( "init" );

    // Forms
    var formsPlugin = $( "body" ).forms();
    formsPlugin.forms( "init" );

    // Load mail services
    var serviceMail = $.services.serviceMail();
    serviceMail.subscribe( $(".form--subscribe") ); 
    // Subscribe to the  MailChimp e-mail list
    serviceMail.contact( $(".form--contact") );

    // Register for training
    var serviceTraining = $.services.serviceTraining();
    serviceTraining.register( $(".form--training-register") );

});
```

});

As always, all suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two `paths` that point to the same file is *in general* a good way to get loading errors. (I say "in general" because there may be specific cases that will work. It is just luck though. You're not supposed to do it.)

What you should do is use instead of `paths` the [`bundles`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) configuration option:

```
bundles: {       
'custom/release/release.min': ['layout', 'forms', 
                               'serviceTraining', 'serviceMail']
}
```

This tells RequireJS that when you want to load any of the four modules in the array, it should load the module `custom/release/release.min` to find them.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. Apparently I needed to use the bundle name at the require statement: require(['custom/release/release.min'], function() { etc..